# DotNetNuke is not sending out mails using SMTP Server

Tags: email, smtp, dotnetnuke

I have configured my DNN mail server to send out mail using our companies Email service provider. I cannot send any emails to external email server.

For ex. My email provider is `testx@ttt.com`. I can send emails to `testy@ttt.com` and `textz@ttt.com`. However i cannot send to `testy@gmail.com` or `testy@hotmail.com`

The error i see in the DNN event viewer is as below

```
System.Net.Mail.SmtpFailedRecipientsException: Unable to send to all recipients. 
System.Net.Mail.SmtpFailedRecipientException: Mailbox unavailable. 
The server response was: This domain is not hosted here
```

I have the same email address configured in my outlook and i can send/recieve to any emails like gmail or hotmail. Following are my DNN email settings

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like one or two things might be happening here:

1. Your SMTP server isn't set up to allow relaying from the IP address of your web server.
2. You may need to create an SPF ([Sender Policy Framework](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sender_Policy_Framework)) or TXT record in DNS for your SMTP server's primary domain that allows SMTP traffic from the IP address of the server where your DNN website is hosted.  An SPF record may already be in use for your email domain, but generally you'd add something like this to it:  `v=spf1 a ip4:1.2.3.4 -all`, where `1.2.3.4` is the IP address of your web server.